# DataColumns and Captions

Tags: c#, dataset, caption

I'm trying to set up user-friendly captions in a DataSet which will be detected by an Infragistics grid during the binding process. I seem to recall that it was possible to do this in the underlying XSD of the typed dataset but any relevant links to this seem to have fallen off Google's relevant link list.

Has anyone done this, would recommend it or have a better method? I don't need to localise strings as this is an internal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might you be referring to the msdata:Caption attribute?

```
<xs:element name="colname" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"
  msdata:Caption="Friendly Caption" />
```